# access to ntfs stream for a very long filename fails

Tags: windows, winapi, stream, ntfs

Having a little trouble while accessing an alternate ntfs stream from a file with a very long  name (more that `MAX_PATH` characters long, created using "\\?\" prefix according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#short_vs._long_names)). For the first time i thought it's my mistake in code, but then I tried a cmd command:

> more < "\\?\c:\!!!Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long filename!!!.png:streamname"

and it fails with an error that file is not found. The file exists and it's contents can be read, but I cannot access the stream I need for read and write.
I don't want my software to be unable to work with long filenames, so I'm searching for any workarounds for this situation.

I know that I can use [BackupRead function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I'm not sure if this solution can be fast on a large files and it will not work in 2000.

GetShortPathName gives me the same fail result, are there any other APIs that can shorten a filename? I really dont want to do this using a temporary junction with a short filename. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Firstly the prefix you want is \\?\ (you are missing a leading slash in your example). Second the DOS prompt doesn't actually support this form of path and I'd be surprised if the `more` command did either.

Comment: The MSDN documentation is unfortunately misleading.  BackupRead() exists and is perfectly functional on Windows 2000, but since Windows 2000 is no longer supported it gets scrubbed from the documentation.

Comment: mistyped the \\?\, right. But CreateFile fails also with GetLastError=2, when i try to acces the stream with "longfilename:streamname" as lpFileName value. So there is no way to do this without BackupRead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the very helpful page on [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) says referring to the `lpFileName` parameter which specifies the filename:

> In the ANSI version of this function, the name is limited to MAX_PATH
>   characters. To extend this limit to 32,767 wide characters, call the
>   Unicode version of the function and prepend "\?\" to the path.

Since you are contemplating `BackupRead` obviously you are wanting to access this stream programatically. If so, test things programatically. Trying all these operations from the command prompt is a crap-shoot and will not establish anything more than the ability to perform such operations from the command prompt.

With that in mind, let's try this simple program - boilerplate code removed:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE,
                       HINSTANCE,
                       LPTSTR,
                       int)
{
    /* This is the name of the file that we will try to create. Please note that
     * I have hardcoded the path to my user directory (C:\Users\nikb), and since 
     * it's unlikely that path exists on your computer, you should probably put
     * something there that makes sense.
     */
    LPCWSTR lpszFileName = L"\\\\?\\c:\\users\\nikb\\!!!Long long long long "
                           L"long long long long long long long long long long "
                           L"long long long long long long long long long long "
                           L"long long long long long long filename!!!.png:streamname";

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(lpszFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, 
        CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        BYTE bBuffer[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'N', 'i', 'k', '!' };
        DWORD dwSize = 10;

        if(WriteFile(hFile, bBuffer, dwSize, &dwSize, NULL))
            ::MessageBoxW(GetDesktopWindow(), L"Success", L"WriteFile", MB_OK);
        else
            ::MessageBoxW(GetDesktopWindow(), L"Failure", L"WriteFile", MB_OK);

        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }

    return 0;
```

}

This should work just fine. So now, let's make that filename longer by adding a few more words to it. Again, be sure to properly update the path to something valid on your machine.

```
LPCWSTR lpszFileName = L"\\\\?\\c:\\users\\nikb\\!!!Long long long long long long long "
                       L"long long long long long long long long long long long "
                       L"long long long long long long long long long long long "
                       L"long long long long long long long long long long long "
                       L"long long long long long long long long long long long "
                       L"long long long long long long long long long long long "
                       L"long long long long long long long long long long long "
                       L"long long filename!!!.png:streamname";
```

Now that's **long**. And it will fail. Weird... If we check the output of `GetLastError()` we will get `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` so what gives? This should work because it clearly isn't longer then 32,767 characters and we're using the fancy `\\?\` syntax to let us specify *reeeeeally* long paths. Right?

Well... sort of. The MSDN page on `CreateFile` links to the very helpful page titled [Naming Files, Paths and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx). As a matter of fact, even you linked to that page in your question. Which is interesting, because it would have answered your question before you even asked it:

> The Windows API has many functions that also have Unicode versions to
>   permit an extended-length path for a maximum total path length of
>   32,767 characters. This type of path is composed of **components**
>   separated by backslashes, **each up to the value returned in the
>   lpMaximumComponentLength parameter of the GetVolumeInformation
>   function (this value is commonly 255 characters)**. To specify an
>   extended-length path, use the "\?\" prefix. For example, "\?\D:\very
>   long path".

So although the path itself may be 32,767 characters long no individual component (i.e. "part") of the path may exceed the largest value allowed by the filesystem.  Indeed, if you try to find out what the maximum component length that NTFS reports back, it will be 255.

So the filename is a single component, and a single component may not be longer than 255 characters. The filename which you specified was:

> !!!Long long long long long long long long long long long long long
>   long long long long long long long long long long long long long long
>   long long long long long long long long long long long long long long
>   long long long long long long filename!!!.png:streamname

A quick test shows that this is 264 characters long. And 264, it should come as no surprise, is greater than 255.

Comment: Thanks, that means I have to use BackupRead and BackupWrite functions in that case.

Comment: @Sega-Zero Huh? How does that help? You're hitting a limitation of the underlying filesystem. It's not the API that is limiting you, and `BackupRead` and `BackupWrite` won't help.

Comment: that helps me with the fact, that longfilename + ":streamname" may be more than MAX_PATH, so I can use BackupRead with longfilename < MAX_PATH
I mean i've already created the file, but couldn't access the stream, because total filename were > MAX_PATH :)